# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: map and map

Tags: python

I am trying to debug the following code where I get the aforementioned error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'map'

I did my fair search online and I understand that the square operation is not supported but I cannot fully understand how to resolve it.

My code is the following:

```
mahalanobis = lambda p: distance.mahalanobis(p, means, covariances.T)
d = np.array(map(mahalanobis, data))  # Mahalanobis distance values 
d2 = d ** 2  # MD squared
```

The error pops up in the square calculation. All data types are numpy.ndarrays.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert `map` into `list`:

```
d = np.array(list(map(mahalanobis, data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), `map()` returns an iterable while, in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map), it returns a list. Any mathematical operation, like squaring (`**`), on a python iterable would throw similar error. The line:

```
d2 = d ** 2
```

throws the mentioned error in Python 3 as `d` is an iterable returned by the function `map()`. It is likely that you are working in Python 3. So you need to convert `d` into list before any mathematical operation, like so, `d = np.array(list(map(mahalanobis, data)))`.